# Memory Viewer/Debugger for VBA

Tags: windows, debugging, hex-viewer, vba, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to understand the layout of VBA code in memory, how COM objects are structured, what VBA functions look like under the hood etc.

I want something like this:

[image: Example Gif]

I.e. a GUI that has some of the following features:

- Lets me find some address at runtime and see the values displayed in hex and ascii.
- As I step through the VBA code, changes are highlighted (e.g. in red).
- Allow me to edit memory values manually.

I don't quite understand how memory works on a computer and whether it is possible for a random bit of software to inspect my VBA memory at runtime.